# VS 2019 для запуска c++ win Forms требует какой то dll файл с названием самого проекта, выдает ошибку, и не собирает проект

Tags: c++, winforms, dll, visual-studio-2019

[image: Упорно отказывается стартовать и требует данный файл. Как его создать?]

VS 2019 для запуска c++ win Forms требует какой то dll файл с названием самого проекта, выдает ошибку, и не собирает проект. Порыл интернет, ответов на данный вопрос так и не нашел

Comment: Явно вы в свойствах проекта указали сборку динамически компонуемой библиотеки, а не выполнимой программы...